# DDD Questions about creation and upgrade of aggregate root with child entitities and its persistence

Tags: design-patterns, service, architecture, aggregate, domain-driven-design

In the application I am working on, **the user can start an Order without Order Lines,** **but the order cannot be persisted without order lines** and other properties where other aggregates are referenced (which in the database are foreign keys which do not accept null values, this is why). **This order is kept in cache until the user confirms it, that is the moment to persist it.**

**I think creating an aggregate root via its constructor leaving it in an inconsistent state regarding its persistence should not be possible.** Is there something wrong with my thinking? because if this is possible, how do I handle the rules for its persistence? In the application service? In your repository? via a function (maybe "IsValidToPersist") in the aggregate root?

I see sense in the fact that **the Order can be created without all the properties it needs for its persistence**, in this case. I usually check for these needs in the aggregate root's constructors, throwing exceptions if the aggregate root is not ready to persist, among other business rules. **I guess if this can be so, then there must be application services like "CreateOrderService", "AddOrderLineService", and "SaveOrderService" / "AddOrderService" where it would persist.** And **not just an "AddOrderService"** service where it is created and persisted at the same time.

To update an Order Line, **should I create an "UpdateOrderLineService"** service that will find the Order, update its order line through its functions? **Or should it be all that it takes to update an Oder in a single service "UpdateOrderService"?**. I think this **second option** complicates some things. For example, it is difficult for the service to know which order lines to add, update and delete. Although that could be solved with a function in Order like "ChangeOrderLines" and simply replace them. In the **first option**, should the Order be persisted with each update (or even addition or deletion) of order lines? I can think of other options such as: return the updated Order or return the updated (or added) Order Lines (although this is not such a good idea).

My question, really is: **is it convenient that exists services to handle the child entities of the aggregate root?**

**Edit (specific information about app):**

My response to @rascio contains more useful specific details for the application:

The application has a tour to "create" a Order. Screen after screen the order is "created". The first screen the user must write a number, without this number the order can't be created. Must be a valid number that it is persisted in db (like discount codes, for example). After that the user can chose the products and later, other things. I need check and save the data user write or choose for each screen. The last screen it's an abstract of order, where user can change things and confirm the order. It's a desktop application. Without side effects. Really not a order, but is very similar.

**Edit 2 (more specific information about app):**

There are two ways to create the order. One going through the tour: introducing the number, the products and the other things. Screen after screen. Once the tour is finished, the summary screen will be displayed where the user can modify and confirm it. Or you can start creating it on this summary screen from scratch. You can also go to this summary screen from any of the other tour screens. If the user had chosen only the number and the products in the tour, these will be the ones that appear in the summary and not the other things, which they can complete in the summary.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "the user can start an Order without Order Lines", what does it mean for the user to start an order? What side effects this has? Does this mean that as soon the order is created if the user close the browser and connect from the smartphone he should see the order?

Comment: The application has a tour to "create" a Order. Screen after screen the order is "created". The first screen the user must write a number, without this number the order can't be created. Must be a valid number that it is persisted in db (like discount codes, for example). After that the user can chose the products and later, other things. I need check and save the data user write or choose for each screen. The last screen it's an abstract of order, where user can change things and confirm the order. It's a desktop application. Without side effects. Really not a order, but is very similar.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest not having foreign key constraints which cross aggregate boundaries.  Enforcing such constraints in the DB infrastructure means that at least one of these two things is true:

- the constraint isn't being enforced in your domain logic, in which case your domain logic isn't fully capturing your domain
- the constraint is being enforced in your domain logic, in which case why are you duplicating things?

It's also the case that if you have things like `ON DELETE CASCADE` as part of that constraint, you're violating the principle that all access to the aggregate is through the root (because the DB definitely isn't going through the root), but this might not necessarily be a problem if there's no operations which could lead to that sort of "behind your back" modification of aggregates.

In this case, it's clear that there's a disagreement between your domain logic (which says "an order without lines is OK") and your DB infra (which says "nope").  If you can't drop the foreign key constraint, then you should duplicate the constraint in your domain logic and not allow an order to be constructed without lines.  That may entail an OrderInProgress aggregate which might not have the same invariants as an Order.

Comment: I don't think that aggregate boundaries is wrong designed. Maybe I don't written specific information about app to it's better understanding. I think that your last paragraph is which has more sense about this problem. Please, I invite you to read the edition I written. Thanks for your reply.

**Edit:** I consider your last paragraph. I think it is a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There's two main ways to model this IMO:

1. An `Order` always needs some order lines or else it's not an `Order`. In that case you are making it an invariant of the `Order` to even exist, so that thing "without order lines" is NOT an `Order`. Perhaps it's a `ShoppingCart`? Perhaps it's an `OrderDraft`? It would be modeled as a concept "similar" to an `Order`, from which the real `Order` would most likely be created.
2. You make the invariant dependent not only on the mere `Order`'s existance, but it's state. For instance, you could see it as **an accepted order must have line items**. In that case perhaps the order starts as **in progress** and needs line items only to transition towards the accepted/submitted/etc. state. In that case the rules would apply upon calling `order.accept()` for instance.

> "then there must be application services like "CreateOrderService", "AddOrderLineService", and "SaveOrderService" / "AddOrderService"

I wouldn't call it "Service" if there's one per use case. I'd call it `XXXUseCase` or `XXXHandler`, but the `Service` suffix is generally used for **wider** interfaces such as:

```java
class OrderService {
    void create(...) { }
    void addLineItem(...) {}
    //...
}
```

Make sure that the use case names aligns with the domain's language (the Ubiquitous Language) rather than technical jargon (e.g. saveOrder).

Comment: Yes, I think that your option one is a good solution. I though some similar, like "OrderCache", because these object don't will be peristed. This is similar, imo to the last paragraph of the reply of Levi Ramsey. Thanks for the suggestion of names. I was naming "Controllers" what you name "Services". Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion stems from an assumption that your DDD entities can directly support a user workflow.  This is not the case.  The user workflow is a UI concern, not your aggregate's.

> the user can start an Order without Order Lines, but the order cannot
> be persisted without order lines

The first part of that requirement is a User experience requirement.  The second part is an invariant for your domain model.

"But this means that to support the UI I'd need to create *similar* objects as I already have in the domain model!?!"

Yup!

> This order is kept in cache until the user confirms it, that is the
> moment to persist it.

Fine, but that cache does not belong in your domain model.  It belongs on the client.

The services I might expect to see in your Bounded Context to support Order handling would include:

- CreateOrder (a fully consistent order only can be provided, not an empty one)
- AddOrderLine (add a line to an existing order)
- UpdateOrderLine (change the details of an existing order line)
- RemoveOrderLine (would automatically delete the order if it is the only line left -- assuming your domain rules are that an order cannot exists without lines).
- RemoveOrder (deletes the order entity and all of its lines).

but it would NOT include:

- SaveOrder

All of the previous services would be persisting at the completion of each command.

> is it convenient that exists services to handle the child entities of
> the aggregate root?

Yes, as I have outlined above.  But that does not extend to helping the user through a 'work-in-progress' during which entities may violate your domain invariants.  That's a task for the client.

Comment: Thanks! I have been follow your advices. I am consider the other user's replies. Later I 
 will write how I have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your domain rules want your order to not have order line in certain states.

From your latest update it seems that to be created, your Order aggregate, has only the invariant related to the number the user needs to put.

This is part of your domain logic.

> This order is kept in cache until the user confirms it, that is the moment to persist it.

This is not a normal "software" cache, this is your domain want to maintain your order with relaxed invariants, until the user do something.

When you "update" an aggregate it can change its internal state, and on different internal states different invariants can be applied.

> I see sense in the fact that the Order can be created without all the properties it needs for its persistence, in this case.

this is totally right to me.

> I guess if this can be so, then there must be application services like "CreateOrderService", "AddOrderLineService", and "SaveOrderService" / "AddOrderService" where it would persist.

more than services I would speak in terms of your domain, these seems to be the commands your aggregate should support.

Looking at what your wrote, it seems to me that a valid sequence of commands can be:

```
CreateOrder(ANumber) -> AddProduct(Product) -> AddProduct(Product) -> AddOtherThings(OtherThings)
```

After each command the state of the aggregate is persisted.
Each command needs its own validation, so:

- `CreateOrder` needs a valid number (not empty, etc...)
- `AddOrderLine` Valid product, and the order should be finalized (you didn't write about this, but I'm supposing after you `AddOtherThings` or something else is done you cannot add any more products to the order
- `AddOtherThings` valid input and at least one product should be part of the order

(This is an example, commands should be modeled also depending what you wat to offer to the user in terms of a "single update persisted atomically", so also an `UpdateOrderLines(OrderLine...))` can make sense in certain cases.)

> how do I handle the rules for its persistence? In the application service? In your repository?

What I want to stress with this response is the fact that an aggregate can have multiple states, and each state can have its own invariants. The role of the Entity/Aggregate in DDD is to maintain true these invariants, and disallow for updates that can move the data into an inconsistent state. So these rules should be handled where you are handling the logic to change the aggregate internal state.

For your last question:

> My question, really is: is it convenient that exists services to handle the child entities of the aggregate root?

These depends on what you mean by "services", application services? Domain services? Something else services? I hate the "service" word as it doesn't have a precise meaning :)
By the way as software components to do, this depends on your generic architecture approach, but what DDD suggests is that all mutations to an aggregate "pass" for the aggregate root, because to enforce the invariants you could need the state of the entire aggregate, for example an OrderLine entity can be updated only if the Order entity (aggregate root) is in a certain state.
It doesn't matter what software components you do, the important thing is that they treat you entire aggregate as a single atomic unit of data, like it doesn't support concurrent modification, so that at each mutation invariants regarding the data of the aggregate can be checked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your vision is of great help to me. It seems like a good idea to create a command (I'm calling it (application) services) for every possible user action regarding the aggregate. But I doubt if the Order should persist. The business asks me to save the Order only if the user completes the Order. This means you have to assign that number, the products and the other things, they are all required. If the user does not finish the order, it is not saved. The user can also modify all these choices on the summary screen or even start creating the Order from this screen.

Comment: I see it in the following way. There are two ways to create the order. One going through the tour: introducing the number, the products and the other things. Screen after screen. Once the tour is finished, the summary screen will be displayed where the user can modify and confirm it. Or you can start creating it on this summary screen from scratch. You can also go to this summary screen from any of the other tour screens. If the user had chosen only the number and the products in the tour, these will be the ones that appear in the summary and not the other things, ...

Comment: ... which they can complete in the summary.

Comment: I don't see big issues in saving the order in an "incomplete" state, that will be changed into something else later. BTW your UI should talk with your domain through commands, if you don't store the aggregate from your UI when not yet complete, in that moment you should bot use the aggregate, but maybe you can prepare a CreateOrder command that will later be executed to create the aggregate

Comment: Exists problems if the order is saved in an incomplete state for other business reasons. In other apps is necessary read all orders and these must be in a complete state. Finally I create other Aggregate called OrderInProgress (I prefer to create a property "IsInProgress" or an Enumerable "State" for some reasons) and a repository that save this in memory. I don't know if is the better solution, but I'm running out of time for the presentation, unfortunately :(